# Insert into SQLite database with Swift 3

Tags: sqlite, swift3, sqlite.swift

I am trying to save data into an sqlite database with the below function.

```
func insertSpecieDetail(_ specieId: Int)
{
    //
    //  Create a temporary SpecieDetailModel for storing our values from the query.
    //
    let specieDetail: SpecieDetailModel = SpecieDetailModel()

    //
    //  Create an instance of our statement for SQLite to use.
    //
    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil


    let update:String = String(format:SQL.InsertUserUpdates, specieId)
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.database, update, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {

        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, specieDetail.userCommonName, -1, nil);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, specieDetail.userCommonNameFR, -1, nil);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, specieDetail.userCommonNameES, -1, nil);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, specieDetail.userCommonNameDE, -1, nil);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, specieDetail.userNotes, -1, nil);

        if sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE {
            print("Successfully inserted row.")
        } else {
            print("Could not Update row.")
        }
    }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement)
}
```

SQL.InsertUserUpdates =

```
"INSERT INTO RL_Species (user_common_name, user_common_name_fr, user_common_name_es, user_common_name_de, user_notes) VALUE (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" + "WHERE RL_Species.id = %d"
```

Not getting any errors, but the system is skipping over after the command:

`if sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.database, update, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK`

On this same line, I checked what "update" equals and is below

```
"INSERT INTO RL_Species (user_common_name, user_common_name_fr, user_common_name_es, user_common_name_de, user_notes) VALUE (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)WHERE RL_Species.id = 8"
```

so it seems that the string is finding the specieId OK.

What am I missing?

UPDATE:
Found the VALUE vs. VALUES error, but still am getting an error "near" WHERE.

```
func insertSpecieDetail(_ specieId: Int)
{
    //
    //  Create a temporary SpecieDetailModel for storing our values from the query.
    //
    let specieDetail: SpecieDetailModel = SpecieDetailModel()

    //
    //  Create an instance of our statement for SQLite to use.
    //
    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil

    let update = "INSERT INTO RL_Species (user_common_name, user_common_name_fr, user_common_name_es, user_common_name_de, user_notes) VALUES ('\(specieDetail.commonName)', '\(specieDetail.commonNameFR)', '\(specieDetail.commonNameES)', '\(specieDetail.commonNameDE)', '\(specieDetail.userNotes)') WHERE RL_Species.id = '\(specieId)';"

    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {


        if sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE {
            print("Successfully inserted row.")
        } else {
            print("Could not Update row.")
        }
    } else {

        // forces SQLite to send error message
        let errorMessage = String.init(validatingUTF8: sqlite3_errmsg(database))!
        print("update failed! \(errorMessage)")        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement)
}
```

Comment: Where did you get that code from? The last parameter of `sqlite3_bind_text()` must not be `nil`. And to get a useful error message, call [sqlite3_errmsg()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).

Comment: Thank you, the error message helped a lot.  I found that I was using VALUE and not VALUES.  But, it seems that was the first of the errors.  I am getting an error "near" WHERE, but cannot find it.  I have updated the original post to reflect a change made to eliminate the nil.

Comment: Just use the [correct parameter value](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) (when in doubt, SQLITE_TRANSIENT). And [INSERT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) has no WHERE.

Comment: Thanks, CL.  It took me a while but i figured it out.  It seems there were a few errors and had to restructure it in order for it to work.  The sqlite3_errmsg() suggestion is what helped a ton.  Thank you

Comment: When I use the SQLITE_TRANSIENT, I get an error of an unresolved identifier.